# Get only the current class members via Reflection

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, system.reflection

Assume this chunk of code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestFunctionality
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
      Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("c:\\testclass.dll");
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assembly.GetName());
      var alltypes = assembly.GetTypes();
      foreach (var t in alltypes)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
        var methods = t.GetMethods(/*BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly*/);
        foreach (var method in methods)
        Console.WriteLine(
        "\t--> "
        +(method.IsPublic? "public ":"")
        + (method.IsPrivate ? "private" : "") 
        + (method.IsStatic ? "static " : "") 
        + method.ReturnType + " " + method.Name);
      }
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to get the definition of methods that are defined in this class but **not** from the base class. ie, I don't want to get things like

```
System.String ToString() // A method in the base class object.
```

How can I filter them out?

I tried to pass `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` but that filters everything.
This is inside **testclass.dll** :

```
namespace TestClass
{
public class Class1
    {
      public static int StaticMember(int a) { return a; }
      private void privateMember() { }
      private static void privateStaticMember() { }
      public void PublicMember() { }
      public void PublicMember2(int a) { }
      public int PublicMember(int a) { return a; }
    }
}
```

What do you suggest?

Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You want this:

```
cl.GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
    BindingFlags.Instance |
    BindingFlags.Public);
```

Per the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it states that `DeclaredOnly`:

> Specifies that only members declared at the level of the supplied type's hierarchy should be considered. Inherited members are not considered.

Now, maybe you explicitly want methods that *aren't* `public`:

```
cl.GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
    BindingFlags.Instance |
    BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

If you want **both** `public` and non-`public` method, do this:

```
cl.GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
    BindingFlags.Instance |
    BindingFlags.Public |
    BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Notice that each query contains `Instance` and `Public` or `NonPublic`, that's because the documentation states the following:

> You must specify **Instance** or **Static** along with **Public** or **NonPublic** or **no members will be returned**.

Comment: +1 Note: For private members this is the default behavior. You'll get only declared members.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, wait, wouldn't `NonPublic` also grab `protected` members? Those would be inherited.

Comment: I have to admit I considered withholding my +1 for use of the phrase "The options are pretty limitless". I'm sure there aren't more than about a million options... ;-)

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I don't think `protected` will be retieved. Am lazy to test. I guess it is true for all non public.

Comment: when I use DeclaredOnly, I get nothing but the class name.
I updated the question to show a better example code.

Comment: @AramAzhari, please see my edit. There are two binding flags that are always required, `Instance` or `Static` and `Public` or `NonPublic`, please accept my apologies.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I also added static so I get those methods too. This is what I ended up with for this to work:

    BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
    BindingFlags.Instance |
    BindingFlags.Static |
    BindingFlags.Public |
    BindingFlags.NonPublic

Comment: @AramAzhari, you got it friend! Now you're getting the more abstract concept.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `DeclaredOnly` binding flag

Comment: it has to be a combination of flags otherwise you don't get results